# App MediaRecorder program ANR

Tags: android, android-mediarecorder

I create the application like this:

The code for beginning recording

```
public static void startRecording() {

if (recordTime == 0) {
if (null == mr) {
mr = new MediaRecorder();
}
path = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),
"myRecording.3gp");
mr.reset();
```

Get the ΪMicphone music volime

```
mr.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
mr.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);
mr.setOutputFile(path.getAbsolutePath());
mr.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);

try {
mr.prepare();
} catch (IOException e) {
}
mr.start();
Record.recordTime = 1;
}
}
```

End recording

```
public static void stopRecording() {
if (mr != null) {
// mr.reset();
mr.stop();
mr.release();
mr = null;
Record.recordTime = 0;
}

}
```

I repeated fast call recording 
I call the recording fast repeatedly and stop the recording process, it will appear ANR phenomenon. 
Who knows what the problem is?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Mind adding logcat. With that would be easier to find your ANR cause. By the way; you are not doing this in the UI thread, are you?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well... this post is a little old, but since i am with a very similar case, the explanation of the problem posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12519677/android-media-recorder-stop) makes sense to me.

When you stop the recording, the video will be saved on the phone memory (internal or SD Card). Since this is an heavy I/O operation, the application may not respond for some time, causing the ANR.

I don't know, but have you tried to put the stop on a different thread ? This may work for you.

```
    public static void stopRecording() {
    if (mr != null) {
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                mr.stop();
                mr.release();
                mr = null;
                Record.recordTime = 0;
            }
        }).start();
    }
}
```